# Android application built with api 22 and not working in api 19

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am developing an Android application with Android Studio and when I ran the project, it worked fine on my Intel 1505 with Android 5.1 running on it.

After deploying, I shared the application. It successfully installed, but when I ran it the project crashed.

Comment: Without the logcat is quite impossible to answer

Comment: 1) You should never ever ever publish the application before testing it on most (if not all) supported platforms, at least via emulators. 2) Please debug-run the app in API 19 and post stacktrace of crash here, this way no one on earth can know what is going wrong.

Comment: You can't use API 22 features on API 19 device. You have to wrap them in `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) { ... }`. Replace 21 with the API version when the feature used inside the if block was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the support libraries in the proyect.
[check some documentation about this here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: This might be the right answer, but good quality answers should quote appropriately from the link source and explain how it answers the question.